# How is application working without onCreate method?

Tags: android

I've imported google drive quick start project and it's MainActivity contains these functions:

```
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity.onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity.onConnected(Bundle)
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity.onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity.onDisconnected()
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity.onPause()
com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity.onResume()
```

How does it work without onCreate method?

Comment: Have you seen its super class? Maybe the super class has the onCreate you are looking for...

Comment: It's super class is Activity.class.
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener {...}

Comment: Do you understand how inheritance works?

Comment: yes, the methods from super class are already in child class and can be over rided.
I think it answered my question as its code then begins from onResume().

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think you mean `Activity` `onCreate` method, not `Application` `onCreate` as you mentioned in the title. It is not the same. `com.google.android.gms.drive.sample.quickstart.MainActivity` implements android `Activity` therefore it contains default implementation of `onCreate()`.